# Laravel: Redis cache in background issue

Tags: php, laravel, caching, redis, cron

I have a schedule task which runs every 5 minutes.

This schedule command puts some data to Redis cache via controller.

##### **`Kernel.php`**

```php
...
protected $commands = [
   Commands\DataCommand::class,
];

protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
{
   $schedule->command('data:cache')->everyFiveMinutes()->onOneServer()->runInBackground();
}
```

##### **`DataCommand.php`**

```php
...
public function handle()
{
   app('App\Http\Controllers\DataProcessing')->setCache();
}
```

##### **`DataProcessing.php`**

```php
...
public function setCache()
{
   $data = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
   Cache::store('redis')->put('data', $data, now()->addMinutes(10));
}
```

This doesn't work with `runInBackground`. When I am trying to get `data` from the cache it returns `null` anyway.

So, when I remove `->runInBackground()` it works perfectly and then I can get `data` from Redis cache as expected.

The problem that it executes sequentially in foreground but I want to run all schedule tasks simultaneously in background.

Why I can't access cache when task is running in background and how to overcome this issue?

Comment: How do you run the scheduler? have you tried manually executing the scheduler etc.?

Comment: My scheduler is configures according to official Laravel docs. Cron job runs this: `* * * * * cd /path-to-your-project && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`. Can there be any system restrictions especially on the background tasks? Or maybe user scope/privileges?